# h:datatable headerClass is not seen by my custom style

Tags: html, css, jsf

I want to use CSS on the header of a dataTable in JSF but for some reason I cant? I've tried a few different approaches with this but none of them worked and I assumed it would be easy after getting the rows to use CSS.

CSS:

```
.table-header{ 
    text-align:center;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5E5E5;
    border-bottom:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    padding:16px;
    }
.table-odd-row{
     background:#F8F8F8;
}
.table-even-row{
     background:#80ffff;
}
```

xHTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"

    >

<h:head>
    <title>Manu table</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css"  /> 
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{manufacturerController.loadManufacturers()}" type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Add Manufacturer" action="ManufacturerInput" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{manufacturerController.manufacturers}" var="m"
                 headerClass="table-header" rowClasses="table-odd-row,table-even-row">
            <h:column >                 
             <f:facet name="header">Manu Code</f:facet>                 
                    #{m.manu_code}
             </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Manu Name</f:facet>
                    #{m.manu_name}
             </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Manu Details</f:facet>
                    #{m.manu_details}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
                    <h:link value="Update" outcome="ManuUpdate" />
                    <br></br>
                    <h:link value="Delete" outcome="ManuDelete" />
            </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>  
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide the html source output from any browser for that?

Comment: Why did you tag this with jdbc?

Comment: Learn about css specificity. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/

Comment: I tagged it with jbdc as thats what im using to interact with the database and assumed someone would ask anyway.